# AngularJS check condition and return true or false

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

I have html like this :

```
<td><span ng-if="isuser(user) == false" type="button" >not allowed</span> </td>
```

the above html is displayed only if the function `isuser(user)` return false.

I have an array like this :

```
$scope.list = ["456", "111", "459"];
```

Now the user object has an array called `id`. This `id` array contains a `number` key whose value can be `456`,`111` or `459` and sometimes it may be `empty` also.

The user object :

```
{"name":"pravin","status":"Live","id":[{"number":"111"}],"msg":"test"}
```

Here is the `isuser` function :

```
$scope.isuser = function(user) {
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.list.length; i++){
  var exists = user.id.find(({number}) => number === $scope.list[i]);
  }
if (exists)
  return true;
else
  return false;
};
```

but this always returns false.

I want the for loop to check if none of the values of the number key exists in the list array and then only return false.
 How do I do it?

Comment: post user object also

Comment: Please post `user.id` array.

Comment: posted. check the updated post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the below statement

```
var exists = user.id.find(({number}) => number === $scope.list[i]);
```

updates every time the `exists` variable and always you'll get the last change.

One approach could be using `some` method by passing a *callback* function as argument.

```
$scope.isuser = function(user) {
   var exists = user.id.some(({number}) => $scope.list.includes(number));
   return exists;
}
```

Comment: this worked. your answer is minimal and very efficient

Comment: please take a look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55591159/optimise-ng-bind-directive-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will help you

```
  $scope.isuser = function(user) {
       var exists = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.list.length; i++){
      exists = user.id.find(({number}) => number === $scope.list[i]);
    }
     if(i==$scope.list.length-1){
      if (exists)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
      }
  loop };
```