# Optimise ng-bind directive in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, performance, optimization, ng-bind, ng-filter

In my angular js app I have an array of objects `$scope.time` which contain a name, the current time and another defined time in milliseconds.
In the front-end I'm using `ng-bind` to calculate the difference between these two time and display it in H:m:s format. Please run the code below.

```js
var app = angular.module('angularapp', []);
app.filter("msTotime", function() {
  return function(timee,started,ended) {
    var startDate = new Date(started);
    var endDate = new Date(ended);
    var milisecondsDiff = endDate - startDate;
    var final = Math.floor(milisecondsDiff/(1000*60*60)).toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumIntegerDigits: 2}) + ":" + (Math.floor(milisecondsDiff/(1000*60))%60).toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumIntegerDigits: 2})  + ":" + (Math.floor(milisecondsDiff/1000)%60).toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumIntegerDigits: 2}) ;
    var defaulttime = '00:00:00';
    if(final == '-01:-01:-01'){
    return  defaulttime;
    }
    else {
    return final;
  }
}
});
app.controller('list', function($scope,$window) {
$scope.time = [{"game":"Halo","now":1554805270181,"time":1554794475267},
{"game":"CODuty","now":1554805270181,"time":1554802957031},
{"game":"WOF","now":1554805270181,"time":1554732154093},
{"game":"WarCraft","now":1554805270181,"time":1554803456875},
{"game":"POP","now":1554805270181,"time":1554803456275},
{"game":"RedBulls","now":1554805270181,"time":1554800620012},
{"game":"Eragon","now":1554805270181,"time":1554433320072}];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="angularapp">
<div ng-controller="list" >
<div ng-repeat="timer in time">
<h5>{{timer.game}}</h5><hr>
Milliseconds to H:M:S for  {{timer.game}} <p style="display:inline-block" ng-bind="realtime | msTotime:timer.time:timer.now"></p><br>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The `$scope.time` array is dynamic as I get that data from an api(I defined it hardcoded here for the purpose of demonstration).
The above code works smoothly when I have a few objects in the `$scope.time` array. But when there are thousands of objects then my browser starts to lag as the `msTotime` filter keeps calculating the difference between the milliseconds and converts it to `H:m:s` and binds it to the frontend.

Now the issue is that my browser consumes 40 percent CPU when there are 1000 objects. I believe it's not an issue with `ng-repeat` as when I commented out `<p style="display:inline-block" ng-bind="realtime | msTotime:timer.time:timer.now">` the cpu usage was just 5 percent with more than 1000 objects.

Is there any way to optimize the `ng-bind` directive here or do the time calculation in some other way so that the calculations done by `msTotime` filter don't consume so much CPU.

Comment: you could use a track by in repeat loop so that only if data changes, the list will get updated

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use **lodash** https://lodash.com library to append the time diffrence in each object instead using `directive` to do that. so each time you get data from query use `_.each` to do the same operation and insert var `realtime`.

```js
var app = angular.module('angularapp', []);

app.controller('list', function($scope,$window) {

  $scope.time = [
    {"game":"Halo","now":1554805270181,"time":1554794475267},
    {"game":"CODuty","now":1554805270181,"time":1554802957031},
    {"game":"WOF","now":1554805270181,"time":1554732154093},
    {"game":"WarCraft","now":1554805270181,"time":1554803456875},
    {"game":"POP","now":1554805270181,"time":1554803456275},
    {"game":"RedBulls","now":1554805270181,"time":1554800620012},
    {"game":"Eragon","now":1554805270181,"time":1554433320072}
  ];

  _.each($scope.time, function(obj, index){   
      var startDate = new Date(obj.time);
      var endDate = new Date(obj.now);
      var milisecondsDiff = endDate - startDate;
      var final = Math.floor(milisecondsDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60)).toLocaleString(undefined, {
        minimumIntegerDigits: 2
      }) + ":" + (Math.floor(milisecondsDiff / (1000 * 60)) % 60).toLocaleString(undefined, {
        minimumIntegerDigits: 2
      }) + ":" + (Math.floor(milisecondsDiff / 1000) % 60).toLocaleString(undefined, {
        minimumIntegerDigits: 2
      });
      var defaulttime = '00:00:00';
      if (final == '-01:-01:-01') {
        obj.realtime = defaulttime;
      } else {
        obj.realtime = final;
      }
  });
    
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.core.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="angularapp">
<div ng-controller="list" >
<div ng-repeat="timer in time">
<h5>{{timer.game}}</h5><hr/>
Milliseconds to H:M:S for {{timer.game}} <p style="display:inline-block;">{{timer.realtime}}</p><br>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll try this one